# diff command says file exists, but I cannot find said file

Tags: terminal

I am using rsync to make a duplicate of an ExFAT-formatted external HD to another external HD. At the end of the copy, I got a message saying some files had vanished during the copy. So I used diff to see what files weren't copied. There are a lot of files starting in ._ that weren't copied, so I'll try using dot_clean to fix those and re-copy. But there's another weirder problem.

Diff tells me a certain file exists 'Only in /volumes/[...]' so I go that directory and do a ls -a and that file doesn't show up in the list. I do a diff again and it again says the file is there. (It is not a . file btw.) There are 20 or so files like this according to diff.

Is there any reason a file would not show up in ls -a?

Comment: ls -a will only list files in current directory.

Comment: From command line you can type 'locate filename' or  'find . name filename'

Comment: First, I would not recommend removing "._" (AppleDouble) files -- they contain metadata that ExFAT volumes cannot store natively, and (depending on exactly how you did the sync) `rsync` probably did the right thing, and converted them to actual metadata. `diff` will show this as a missing file, but it's actually exactly what you want. As for the other "Only in ..." files, I'd need to know details (like, an example filename and `ls -a` on the directory that *should* contain it).